# Sessions and Injection in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am creating an mvc project and am testing it with Unity.

I have created a session service which gets and sets the data from the context (see below)

```
public class SessionService : ISessionService
{

    private IConfiguration _Configuration;
    private ILog _Log;
    private HttpContext _Context;

    private T GetSession<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    private void SetSession(string key, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }

    public SessionService(HttpContext context, IConfiguration configuration, ILog log)
    {
        _Configuration = configuration;
        _Log = log;
        _Context = context;

    }

    public SessionModel SessionModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (GetSession<SessionModel>("SESSION_SESSIONMODEL") == null)
            {
                SetSession("SESSION_SESSIONMODEL", new SessionModel());
            }
            return GetSession<SessionModel>("SESSION_SESSIONMODEL");
        }
        set { SetSession("SESSION_SESSIONMODEL", value); }
    }

}
```

Within my testing, i am mocking a session (as per below) and sending it through

```
_TestSessionService = new SessionService(HttpContext.Current, Configuration, _TestLog);

var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "", "");
var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);
var sessionContainer =
            new HttpSessionStateContainer("id",
                                           new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                           new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
                                           10,
                                           true,
                                           HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                           SessionStateMode.InProc,
                                           false);
httpContext.Items["AspSession"] =
            typeof(HttpSessionState)
            .GetConstructor(
                                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                null,
                                CallingConventions.Standard,
                                new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                null)
            .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });
HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
```

This all works fine for testing but when i run the web app, unity fails as it it isnt sending through the httcontect into the sessionservice class.

Can someone help or even better still, provide a complete example that shows how best to handle sessions within mvc for testing and for app use?

Comment: Just curious why `SessionService` accepts `HttpContext` but doesn't use it and instead calls the static `HttpContext.Current`?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't register the HttpContext like this: `container.RegisterType<HttpContext>(new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current));`?  Then the current context should be injected into your class.